# PDO Fetch into class, message

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem with FETCH_CLASS. This part of code not displaying any data from my database.

```
class Names {
   public $name, $mail, $city, $entry;
}

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data');
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Names');
while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
print_r($r);
}
```

Also I have problem with this thing. Nothing happens.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data');

while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
echo $r->message, '<br>';
}
```

And another question. All this code must be always before execute() function, or can It be after somehow?

Comment: You can change the fetch-mode after the `execute` call, too (that answers your second question). The second snippet won't work, simply because the default fetch mode of PDO isn't `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, but `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (a numeric _and_ assoc array). As for why your `FETCH_CLASS` isn't working: have you posted the full class? What does the `data` table look like? Is there a constructor possibly reassigning the properties (use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`)? Is there data in the `data` table? And set the PDO instance to throw exceptions on errors

Comment: Now everthing wroking fine! In second snippet i add FETCH_OBJ and change $r->message, to property i use. And in first one I changed $stmt with $query... That was my mistakes :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for ist query:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data');
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Names');
while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
print_r($r);
}
```